# Semicircle vs hemisphere

Tags: word-usage

- An object shaped like half a circle is called a `semicircle`.
- An object shaped like half a sphere is called a `hemisphere`.

In my native language we do not distinguish. We are in both cases dealing with half of the object (in Danish they are called "half-circle" and "half-sphere", directly translated.)

Is there a reason for this odd difference between the words in English? Is it correctly understand that I *cannot* say `hemicircle` and `semisphere`? The `semi-` seems to be a prefix used predominantly, such as in semi-lines, semi-axes in geometry etc.

Comment: This kind of question is unanswerable. That is just the way it is. hemi is Greek and semi is Latin.

Comment: I don’t think you can. When people do mix them up, people tend to think that it’s a mistake. I feel as if in this case they are not really prefixes, rather just part of the word, which is why you cannot switch them (correct me if I am wrong). It may also have to do something with a circle being 2D and a sphere being 3D, meaning maybe you have to differentiate in english?

Comment: Let's not forget the French 'demi'. In music, _hemidemisemiquaver_ (a 64th note) manages to combine Greek, Latin and French

Comment: @Lambie, and based on the existing answers, it's likely because "circle" is Latin and "sphere" is Greek. This is the best answer to the question. (note the word "likely". It's not a rule that Latin-root word will have Latin prefix, but it's a reasonable explanation why it's more prevalent)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And when you need even smaller notes, they start repeating - [Hemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver) is a thing.  And this word is used *in English* combining 3 other languages.  (There was a recent discussion of this on Music.SE about why this naming system is not popular outside of the UK.)

Comment: @Lambie - You have both called the question unanswerable, and answered it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Nope, I did not answer by saying why. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The basic answer is because a language is what it is, and not what somebody thinks it ought to be.

But historically, the Oxford English Dictionary has

- semicircle - cited from 1526
- hemicircle *obsolete or archaic* - cited from 1603
- semisphere now *rare* - cited from 1659
- hemisphere - cited from 1585.

So the standard forms are older, and the OED derives them respectively from Latin *sēmicirculus* and from "late Latin *hēmisphærium* , < Greek *ἡμισϕαίριον*", whereas the less common alternatives were coined within English, possibly by people who didn't know or didn't care that "circle" is of Latin origin and "sphere" of Greek origin.

Comment: "circle" is of Latin origin and "sphere" of Greek origin <-- I guess this is the crux? If a word is of Latin origin, it's more likely to be given Latin prefix, and similarly for Greek. I wonder why answerers don't put this information first. Like mcalex said on another answer, the word origin is something that we can say objectively. The one we can't say is why we use Latin for circle and Greek for sphere.

Comment: Because it's only marginally relevant, @justhalf. For words of this age it was more relevant - but notice that the rare alternatives I listed above both date from the 1600's, so they're not much more recent. But the coiners of the more recent words _television_, _unprincipled_, and _automobile_ didn't know or didn't care whether the roots were Greek, Latin, or something else. _Amoral_ is an interesting case: the word _immoral_ (formed from Latin sources) already existed; but in the 19th century writers wanted to express a different but related concept, and chose to use a Greek-derived prefix.

Comment: Fair point. My point is something like Nick's answer. This likeliness based on the origin is not a rule, but its something reasonable that warrants mentioning as a reason. Of course any explanation on "why" words are like words today all influenced by how people use it, as all aspects of language, as you said. And for me this is exactly why it's not something that I would mention as the main reason. Only if there are no other reasonable reasons, then I'll answer with the disappointing "it's what it is, since people use it that way"

Comment: Both "circle" and "sphere" were imported into Latin ("circulus", "sphaera") from the Greek ("κίρκος", "σφαῖρα"). So it is misleading to say that one is of Latin origin and the other of Greek origin.

Comment: @TonyK: you're right: I didn't look further back. That makes that side of the argument (which I was already minimising) rather empy. Having said that, I suspect that _circus_ was naturalised in Latin in a way that _sphaera_ was not, but I have no hard evidence for this.

Answer (score 12):

As is often the case with odd quirks like this, it has to do with where the words came from. Both semicircle and hemisphere entered English from Latin via Old French. That probably traces back to the fact that circle has a Latin root and sphere a Greek one. But as always, there's no rule to that sort of etymology and you can't use it to predict what words will be adopted in a language.

Comment: +1 Why do we use the different prefixes?  Because the source words come from different places, possibly at different times. Asked and answered. Why did they come from different places?  *That* is the 'can't be answered' question.